# Add div element to html when upon success of PHP for confirmation of email being sent

Tags: php, html, contacts

I would like to add a particular div element whether or not my php script successfully sent an email. This will show up as a confirmation message saying the email was sent or not that appears on the same page. How do I do this?

```
<?php
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "lewkowicz613@gmail.com";
$subject = "Message from Inspire Health";

if(mail($to, $subject, $first_name. ' '. $last_name. "\r\n" . $email, $message)){
    echo 'Your Message Has Been Sent';
}else{
    echo "Oops! mail not sent";
}

?>
```

This is my HTML part of the form.

```
<section class="section-form js--contact" id="contact">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>Contact Us</h3>
                <h4>Health Coaching/Mailing List</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <form method="post" action="form_process.php" class="contact-form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-messages success">
                            Thank you! Your message has been sent!
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-messages error">
                            Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last name" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
            </div>
        </section>
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You need client side programming for this one

Comment: Your HTML and PHP code are on the same page?

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED**

since from your code you are using an external file to process your form, you can use ajax to handle the request with something like this in your .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#form-name").submit(function(){         

     var data = $("#form-name").serialize();

     $.ajax({
            url: '../form_process.php',
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function()
            {   
                //Validation can be done here
            },
            success: function(response) {
                //Response can come here
                //console.log("response");
                $("#response-place").html(response);
            }
        });

 });

});
```

then your form should be like this:

```
<section class="section-form js--contact" id="contact">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Contact Us</h3>
            <h4>Health Coaching/Mailing List</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <form method="post" id="form-name" class="contact-form">
                <!-- This is where the form response will be displayed -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div id="response-place"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last name" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span-2-of-3">
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Im not sure I understand what to put in the validation  and response part. Also, should I just included this code in my script.js file?

Comment: yes include it in your script.js file. Let me update the above answer for better understanding.

Comment: Im still not understanding how to integrate this code into my project.

Comment: I tried pasting your code into my website but it didnt seem to work. It just displays both success and error messages

Comment: oh sorry i did not remove the messages from your code.  its now working, just make sure you follow your instruction correctly.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to deal with this, would be using php `header()` function to send `$_GET` parameters to your HTML file then read it with PHP and output appropriate message, something like this:

In HTML change this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-messages success">Thank you! Your message has been sent!
    </div>
    <div class="form-messages error">
        Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.
    </div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['success'])) {
          if($_GET['success'] == 't') {
              echo "Thank you! Your message has been sent!";
          }
          else {
              echo "Oops, something went wrong. Please try again.";
          }
      }
 ?>
```

And in your PHP:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $first_name. ' '. $last_name. "\r\n" . $email, $message)){
    header( "Location: index.php?success=t" );
}

else{
    header( "Location: index.php?success=f" );
}
```

However I recommend to go with JBoy answear and do it the asynchronous way with Ajax.